# How to specify when a daemon should stop during system shutdown?

Tags: firefox, shutdown, upstart

I have written a FUSE to combine a local and remote file system as one virtual FS.

The problem I am seeing is that when the system shuts down (i.e. `root` issues a `reboot`), my FS dies before all the running apps (such as FireFox), so when the system comes back up some applications (such as FireFox) are stuck as they weren't able to clean up because the file system disappeared before they could.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, which uses `upstart` -- how do I tell upstart to not kill my FS daemon until the users apps are all dead?

Comment: @karel:  Thanks!  That prompted me to verify the exact version used, and the clients (the machines running the daemon) aren't as far along is I had thought.

Comment: You seem to be using the desktop version of 10.04 (->firefox). That went end of life a while ago (only certain parts (so not even the whole server version) related to the server version of 10.04 are on topic). I would advice to upgrade to 12.04 or 14.04 if you want support from AU. Besides that: you will be missing out on security updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hackish solution is to do this:

```
stop on stopped lightdm
```

replacing lightdm with whatever DM you are using. This will ensure the FS goes down after all user apps are closed.